# Identifying thread running function using concurrent.futures thread pool in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrent.futures

I have the following code:

```
import concurrent.futures

def f(a, b):
    print("Thread x => "+a+" "+b)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
   for n in executor.map(lambda n: f('abcd', 'xpto'), range(3)):
      pass
```

What I want is to be able to replace the **"Thread x"** being the "x" the "thread id/number". The result should be like this:

```
Thread 0 => abcd xpto
Thread 1 => abcd xpto
Thread 2 => abcd xpto
```

The first issue was to pass multiple arguments, but using lambda I was able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to pass x as a parameter?

```py
import concurrent.futures

def f(x, a, b):
    print("Thread”, x, “=>"+a+" "+b)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
   for n in executor.map(lambda n: f(n, 'abcd', 'xpto'), range(3)):
      pass
```

Comment: Yes, just like that. I'm new in python so there's much I don't know :)

Thanks for the quick answer to this simple question. BR